Threads barrier. Thread T6.13 can only end while 6 threads (including itself) are running
• Process’ main thread, i.e. T6.0 must not terminate before the other 43 threads.
• At any time, at most 6 threads of process P6 could be running simultaneously, not counting the main thread.
My code needs to pass some tests. At a certain point, the display stops and enters an infinite cycle.
TH_STRUCT_2 *param = (TH_STRUCT_2*)arg;

sem_wait(param->semaphore);

pthread_mutex_lock(param->lock);
(*param->active_threads)++;
int thread_num = param->thread_num;
pthread_mutex_unlock(param->lock); 

sem_post(param->start_semaphore); 

info(BEGIN, 6, thread_num);

if(thread_num == 13) {
    printf("%d\n", (*param->active_threads) );
    pthread_mutex_lock(param->lock);
    while(*param->active_threads < 6) {
        pthread_cond_wait(param->cond, param->lock);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(param->lock);
}

pthread_mutex_lock(param->lock);
(*param->active_threads)--;
pthread_mutex_unlock(param->lock);

info(END, 6, thread_num); 

if(thread_num == 13 && *param->active_threads == 1) {
    pthread_cond_broadcast(param->cond); 
}

sem_post(param->semaphore); 

return NULL;


pthread_cond_broadcast() is by thread num 13 and if it is on wait in pthread_cond_wait(), then broadcast will never happen. There is no code shown for how threads are launched. If they are contineously created once terminated, then at a point num 13 thread will go on wait and it will not be created later and there will be no broadcast. A check can be given in cond_wait() for 13 to not wait
    while(thread_num != 13 && *param->active_threads < 6) {
Another issue is thread_num is common to all threads assuming param is reused for every thread start. Then thread_num will have race condition. If for example 5 threads are started and they will reach to access param->thread_num at different point of time, then few threads will get wrong thread num. This is not much problem except thread num 13 which holds cond_broadcast()
